# Unable to send OTP code for Xamarin Android Firebase Phone Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, xamarin.android

I am creating a cross platform mobile app (iOS, Android) using xamarin forms and C# and I'm trying to set up user authentication using firebase.

I want to set it up so that when the user wants to log in to their account using their phone number, I first send them an otp code to verify that the phone number they entered is valid. This is the function I created in my Android project:

```
    public Task<bool> SendOtpCodeAsync(string PhoneNumber)
    {
        _PhoneAuthenticationTCS = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        PhoneAuthOptions newOptions = PhoneAuthOptions.NewBuilder().SetPhoneNumber(PhoneNumber).SetTimeout((Java.Lang.Long)60L, TimeUnit.Seconds).SetActivity(Platform.CurrentActivity).SetCallbacks(this).Build();
        PhoneAuthProvider.VerifyPhoneNumber(newOptions);

        return _PhoneAuthenticationTCS.Task;
    }
```

The issue I'm running into is that when I run this, the "newOptions" variable always give me an exception: "Unable to cast object of type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.PointerValue' to type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.PrimitiveValue'."

I'm not sure how to fix this, as it shows up even when I pass in valid phone numbers that are registered in my firebase console. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try to check if there are two different `Mono.Debugger.Soft.dll` assemblies being loaded in your app.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT how do I do that? I'm still kinda new to xamarin